# Adding registry key using reg add creates strange entry - Wow6432Node

Tags: windows, cmd, registry

I am running Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1 64 bit.

If I run the following command on a 32 bit program:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath" /ve /d "C:\Python27" /f
```

What happens is that the registry gets updated like this:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath]
```

Why?  And how can I fix this?

Here is the C code for the program which launches the command:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        char* command = "c:\\temp\\setuppython.cmd";
        PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInformation;     
        STARTUPINFO Info;
        ZeroMemory( &Info, sizeof( Info ) );
        Info.cb = sizeof( Info );

        BOOL success = CreateProcess( NULL, command, NULL,
            NULL, FALSE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,
            NULL, NULL, &Info, &ProcessInformation);

        if(success) {
            // Wait for the process to complete
            WaitForSingleObject( ProcessInformation.hThread, INFINITE);
            printf("cmd %s has finished\n", command);
        }
        else {
            printf("CreateProcess failed for cmd %s\n", command);
        }
}
```

This program is run as a 32 bit executable.  I cannot change this C source code unfortunately so I am looking to fix this in the cmd file somehow.

Here is setuppython.cmd:

```
@echo off

echo setting up python >>C:\temp\results.txt

if EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" (
    echo Running 64 bit Windows >>C:\temp\results.txt
    reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath" /ve /d "C:\Python27" /f
    echo added python reg path: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath" >>C:\temp\results.txt
    reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath" >>C:\CTS\HDC\results.txt
) else (
    echo Running 32 bit Windows >>C:\temp\results.txt
    reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath" /ve /d "C:\Python27" /f
    echo added python reg path: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath" >>C:\temp\results.txt
    reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath" >>C:\temp\results.txt
)

echo finished setting up python >>C:\temp\results.txt
```

Output is like this:

on console:

```
The operation completed successfully.
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
cmd c:\temp\setuppython.cmd has finished.
```

And the contents of results.txt:

```
setting up python 
Running 64 bit Windows 
added python reg path: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath" 
finished setting up python
```

Comment: It's the [\[MSDN\]: Registry Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx). There are lots of articles on this topic (especially on _SO_), here's an example: [\[MSDN\]: Example of Registry Redirection on WOW64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384182(v=vs.85).aspx). If you're not allowed to change the source code, could you at least build it for 64 bit (_x64_ or _AMD64_)? Or (of course as a workaround - not very feasible), run it on a 32bit _Win_. In the **_cmd_ console** type `reg add /?` (notice the `/reg:64` argument).

Comment: you not need use `"\\Wow6432Node\\"` in registry path direct. use paths without it and `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` or `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` modifiers

Comment: So at the end, how would you like to treat the reg entries? Transparent (so both 32bit and 64bit applications running on 64bit _Win_ will modify the **same** value _HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath_)? Note that for 32bit app running on 64bit _Win_, you don't have to manually add _Wow6432Node_, it will be added automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On 64-bit Windows there are two [different registry "views"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx) for certain keys, one for 64-bit applications and one for 32-bit applications.

32-bit specific data is stored under the Wow6432Node key but you should not use this key name in your code. When your batch file detects that it is running on 64-bit Windows it should add the `/reg:32` switch to the reg.exe commands if your goal is to always write to the 32-bit part of the registry:

```
if EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" (
    echo Running 64 bit Windows >>C:\temp\results.txt
    reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath" /ve /d "C:\Python27" /f /reg:32
    echo added python reg path: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath" >>C:\temp\results.txt
    reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath" /reg:32 >>C:\CTS\HDC\results.txt
) else (
    ...
```

> [Note](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129(v=vs.85).aspx)  The Wow6432Node key is reserved. For compatibility, applications should not use this key directly.

Comment: Interesting... I can get the path set in the registry I need if I use /reg:64 - when on 64 bit Windows.

Comment: I have no control over the python source code which does check HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath under 64 bit windows.  So I think my requirement is slightly different to what you think it is.  But your answer is still useful.

Answer (score 3):

I've modified your *.bat* file so that no matter what, it should operate on "*HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath*":

```bat
@echo off

set _RESULTS_FILE="C:\temp\results.txt"
set _PYTHON_REG_KEY="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath"

echo setting up python >>%_RESULTS_FILE%

if "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE:64=%" neq "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" (
    echo Running 64 bit Windows >>%_RESULTS_FILE%
    set _REG_VIEW_ARG=/reg:32
) else (
    echo Running 32 bit Windows >>%_RESULTS_FILE%
)

reg add %_PYTHON_REG_KEY% /ve /d "C:\Python27" /f %_REG_VIEW_ARG%
echo added python reg path: %_PYTHON_REG_KEY% >>%_RESULTS_FILE%
reg query %_PYTHON_REG_KEY% %_REG_VIEW_ARG%>>%_RESULTS_FILE%


echo finished setting up python >>%_RESULTS_FILE%
```

**Notes**:

- I took the liberty of parameterizing the file (with respect of the *results.txt* file name and the registry key - so if one is to be modified to only do it in one place). As a side effect everything that went to "*C:\CTS\HDC\results.txt*" will now go to the default "*C:\temp\results.txt*" (but that could easily be changed)
- I changed the 64bit test (*%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%* could be either *x86* or *AMD64*; I am replacing "*64*" by the empty string "" and then compare the result with the original content). A user could manually create that folder on 32bit machines (could also modify the env var, but in this case, there's a great chance that something else will go wrong before reaching our file), so none of these checks is 100% reliable, but I prefer the one with the var. The difference is that for 32bit apps running on 64bit Win, it won't explicitly specify the `/reg:32` flag (as the app will operate on the 32bit view anyway)
- I didn't test it on 32bit *Win*

*results.txt* content (**with** `set _PYTHON_REG_KEY="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\aaaa"`) after running it from 64 and 32 bit *cmd* windows:

> ```
> setting up python 
> Running 64 bit Windows 
> added python reg path: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\aaaa" 
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\aaaa
>     (Default)    REG_SZ    C:\Python27
>
> finished setting up python 
> setting up python 
> Running 32 bit Windows 
> added python reg path: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\aaaa" 
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\aaaa
>     (Default)    REG_SZ    C:\Python27
>
> finished setting up python
> ```